# Idiomatic bash: set default value for variable

Tags: bash, idioms

How can I set a default value for a bash variable in a concise, idiomatic way? This just looks ugly:

```
if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; then
    option="$1"
else
    option="default"
fi
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
default value               : ${parameter:-word} \
assign default value        : ${parameter:=word}  |_ / if unset or null -
error if empty/unset        : ${parameter:?mesg}  |  \ use no ":" for unset only
use word unless empty/unset : ${parameter:+word} /
```

Comment: +1 for the thorough (albeit maybe a bit too succinct [lack examples]) answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
option=${1:-default}
```

This sets option to the first command line parameter if a first command line parameter was given and not null. Otherwise, it sets option to default. See [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for the details on parameter expansion and some useful variants of this form.

Comment: "Note that if you call your script with an explicit empty first parameter this might behave different from the code in the question." No, it won't, because you used a colon. If you write `${1-default}`, then it will differentiate between an unset and set but empty parameter.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka, thanks, confirmed this in the manual and edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For uses **other** than assigning a default value, which Toxaris already covered, it's worth mentioning that there is a reverse test for `-z`, so instead of

```
if [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; then
    do_something
fi
```

you can simply write:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
    do_something
fi
```

and if there is no `else` branch, you can shorten it to:

```
[ -n "$1" ] && do_something
```

Comment: or simply `if [ "$1" ]; then ...`

Comment: `[ -n "$1" ] && do_something` has a drawback - if `set -e` is set...

Comment: @anishsane As far as `set -e` is concerned, `[...] && command` is the same as `if [...]; then command; fi`. The `[...]` command can safely fail, and `command` will exit the shell if it runs and fails.